# how to remote debug child instance of jboss fuse

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

I go to `/opt/fuse/instances/child/bin`, put the `export KARAF_DEBUG=true` entry in the `/opt/fuse/instances/child/bin/setenv` file. But it does not work.

I could only start the child instance from the root instance karaf console via the admin:start child. I could not start it via `/opt/fuse/instances/child/bin/fuse`.

Any hints or idea will be more than welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the below JVM settings to your child container

> -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5006

- Go to the Fuse console (hawtio)
- Click the required child container from the containers list
- Select settings tab
- Add the above option in the jvmsettings textbox
- Restart the child container

Now you can debug the child container in the specified port (5006)